# Can't transfer an object array with html form

Tags: php, html

i have a little problem with my program and not so experienced in php. I want to transfer an array of objects with a html form to my php file. First i will let you take a look on my code:

*location.php (with executable forms)*

```
<form action="action/add_items.php" method="POST">
        <table border="1" width="20%">
            <thead>
            <th>
                <?= $lang["location_task"][$location->getProperty("location_id")][$location_task->getProperty("location_task_id")]; ?>
            </th>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <?php
            $location_task_items = $location_task->getProperty("location_task_items");

            foreach ($location_task_items as $location_task_item) {
                ?>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <?= $lang["item"][$location_task_item->getProperty("location_task_item_id")]; ?>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <?= $location_task_item->getProperty("location_task_item_value"); ?>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            <?php
            }
            ?>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>
                    <input type="hidden" value="<?php print_r($location_task_items); ?>" name="location_task_items"/>
                    <input type="submit" value="start"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </form>
```

You can see that i only print the array in the input hidden value. Is that right?

*add_items.php*

```
$location_task_items = $_REQUEST["location_task_items"];

foreach($location_task_items as $location_task_item) {
    if($Player_Has_ItemsClass->getObjectByIds($player_id, $location_task_item->getProperty("location_task_item_id")) == null) {
        $player_has_items_attributes = array();
        $player_has_items_attributes["player_has_items_player_id"] = $player_id;
        $player_has_items_attributes["player_has_items_item_id"] = $location_task_item->getProperty("location_task_item_id");
        $player_has_items_attributes["player_has_items_item_value"] = $location_task_item->getProperty("location_task_item_value");

        $player_has_items = new Player_Has_Items($player_has_items_attributes);

        $Player_Has_ItemsClass->insertObject($player_has_items);
    } else {

    }
}
```

I only get the array as string and this exception on the foreach in add_items.php:

> Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

I also tried it with json_encode and json_decode:

```
print_r(json_encode($location_task_items))
json_decode($_REQUEST["location_task_items"]);
```

but only get (object attributes were public):

> Call to undefined method stdClass::getProperty()

Thanks for you help :)

Comment: You cannot print an array into an input like that. Also, I don't think `print_f` is a thing...

Comment: if you get the array as a string is it comma separated?  If so, try looking into the php explode function

Comment: no i get this: "Array ( [0] => Location_Task_Item Object ( [location_task_item_id] => 100 [location_task_item_value] => 10 ) )" but "is_array" gives me a false.

Comment: i also used print_r and printf doesnt work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your hidden field use `json_encode` and then in your destination use [**json_decode**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php):

```
 <input `type="hidden" value='<?php echo json_encode($location_task_items); ?>' name="location_task_items"/>`
```

Comment: i get the same exception and $_REQUEST["location_task_items"] is NULL :/

Comment: Check first the source of your form page and see If it prints a value for the field! then check the usage of Json_decode. @OlliNo.

Comment: okay. var dump of json_encode($location_task_items) looks so:     string(65) "[{"location_task_item_id":"100","location_task_item_value":"10"}]"

Comment: well, look at my answer again, I edited it, don't forget `echo json_encode` and change the value attribute enclose from double quote to single quote @OlliNo.

Comment: I mean by page Source, the HTML source in the browser.

Comment: now i get that, with var dump:                            array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#6 (2) { ["location_task_item_id"]=> string(3) "100" ["location_task_item_value"]=> string(2) "10" } } 
                                                            Fatal error: Call to undefined method stdClass::getProperty() in C:\xampp\htdocs\bg\action\add_items.php on line 10

Comment: At this point and after submit you don't have or it is not supposed to use the hole object (its data and methods) you have just sent its data (properties) so in the destination script receive them in suitable way and iterate through them. Again, check how json_decode works.

Comment: got it! thank you! used "json_decode($_REQUEST["location_task_items"], true)" for an array, foreach it and got the attributes with the string index :)

Answer (score 0):

You could do this

```
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo serialize($location_task_items); ?>" name="location_task_items"/>
```

and then

```
$location_task_items = unserialize($_REQUEST["location_task_items"]);
```

Comment: tried it. get the same exception and cant print it :/

Comment: is $location_task_items an array? what does a var dump look like?

Comment: * array(1) { [0]=> object(Location_Task_Item)#22 (2) { ["location_task_item_id"]=> string(3) "100" ["location_task_item_value"]=> string(2) "10" } }

Comment: like that: "value='<?php print_r(base64_encode(serialize($location_task_items))); ?>'" and "$location_task_items = unserialize(base64_encode($_REQUEST["location_task_items"]));". i get "unserialize(): Error at offset 0 of 220 bytes"